# Using a factory in a class without injecting the whole service manager in ZF2

Tags: php, dependency-injection, zend-framework2

I have a class called *classB* which has multiple dependencies which I am setting up using *ClassBFactory*. Inside *classA* I would like to create a new instance of *classB* using the *classBFactory*.

Is the only way to get a new instance of *classB* from its factory by injecting the whole service container into *classA*, or is there another way? It would seem bad practice to pass in the whole service container as this would give the class access to a lot more than needed.

I've experimented with the following but this won't work as createService() requires the service container, which I would rather not inject into classA

```
class ClassA {
    protected $classBFactory;
    public function __construct(ClassBFactory $classBFactory)
    {
        $this->classBFactory = $classBFactory;
    }

    public function getNewA()
    {
        return $this->classBFactory->createService();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a factory for classA as well where you inject classB into classA. In your factory pull ClassB from the service locator and inject it with contructor injection into ClassA.
You should really try to not let your classes depend on the serviceLocator for various reasons, but only let your factories pull from the servicelocator and inject those dependencies with constructor or setter injection (this is called inversion of control).

**ClassA**

```
class ClassA {
    protected $classB;
    public function __construct(ClassB $classB)
    {
        $this->classB = $classB;
    }
}
```

**Module.php**

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'MyNamespace\ClassA' => function($sm) {
                return new ClassA($sm->get('MyNamespace\ClassB'));
            }, //Using a closure here, but it's better to create a seperate factory class
            'MyNamespace\ClassB' => 'MyNamespace\Factory\ClassBFactory'
        )
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I need to get `ClassA` to return new instances of `classB`, such as in a method `getNewA()` for example. I've updated the question to make this clearer.

Comment: For this use case it sounds ok te me to inject the ServiceManager and retreive classA from it using `get`. Make sure you set shared to false for the service or you'll get the same instance on successive calls.